# PHP include call throws warnings but continues

Tags: php, include

I've got a pretty simple PHP script, but I can't for the life of me work out why one line doesn't work.

The main script:

```
<?php
    include("/includes/processes.php");
?>
[...]
<?php
    if(getUserLevel() == 3) {
        ?>
[...]
```

processes.php is in the right place and all that. It should be defining `getUserLevel()`. Here it is:

```
<?php

function getUserLevel() {
    if(isset($_COOKIE["userlvl"]) && isset($_SESSION["userlvl"]) {
        if($_COOKIE["userlvl"] == $_SESSION["userlvl"]) return $_SESSION["userlvl"];
        else return 0;
    }
    else {
        return 0;
    }
}

function usernameIs($name) {
    if($_COOKIE["username"] == $name && $_SESSION["username"] == $name) return true;
    else return false;
}

?>
```

So when I go to `index.php` (the main script), it gives me two warnings and one fatal error:

```
Warning: include(/includes/processes.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/u164546666/public_html/index.php on line 2
Warning: include(): Failed opening '/includes/processes.php' for inclusion (include_path='.:/opt/php-5.5/pear') in /home/u164546666/public_html/index.php on line 2
Fatal error: Call to undefined function getUserLevel() in /home/u164546666/public_html/index.php on line 27
```

(line 2 is the `include()` call, line 27 the call to `getUserLevel()`)

It's pretty obvious why I've got the fatal error - because the `include()` has failed - but why is that? Is it a server config issue or have I just written it wrong?

The file tree:

```
index.php
/includes
    /processes.php
```

Comment: Show the file tree? Where, in relation to this file, is `includes/`?

Comment: File tree edited in.

Comment: `include("/includes/processes.php");` is used absolute path. Usually used `include(__DIR__ . '/path_related_to_file_from_current_directory.php')`

Comment: Absolute path is deliberate, it's not meant to be relative

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are probably need the relative path and is missing the `.`

```
<?php
    include("./includes/processes.php");
?>
```

Comment: This.  Unless the file is physically included in ROOTFS/includes/processes.php you are using an absolute path which links to the root of your disk.

Comment: That's deliberate, it's not meant to be a relative path.

Comment: Judging from the file tree you have, the `/includes` directory is in the same directory as `index.php`, not the root of the disk

Comment: That is the root of the disk

Comment: From your error message, it looks like `index.php` is in `/home/u164546666/public_html/index.php`, which is not at the root

Comment: Once again, you're going to have to go relative, or switch to include "/home/name/some/folder/includes/processes.php"; as /includes/processes.php is relative to the root filesystem.  PHP does not process includes the same way that HTML links work (with relativity or absolute values)

Comment: Right, I get it. So PHP includes use the **server** root rather than the **hosting** root like HTML, correct?

Answer (score 1):

Change your include to

```
include_once dirname(__FILE__) . "/includes/processes.php";
```

However, I'd go for `require` as the file includes vital functionality.

> require is identical to include except upon failure it will also produce a fatal E_COMPILE_ERROR level error. In other words, it will halt the script whereas include only emits a warning (E_WARNING) which allows the script to continue.

Comment: What's the difference between include and include_once?

Comment: As the name suggests. `include_once` will only include that file once during the execution. `include` will include the file multiple times (if it's called multiple times), and can cause errors thrown (`Cannot redeclare Class Foo` etc)

Answer (score -2):

The issue is with your include statement. Just get rid of the parenthesis around that as:

```
include "/includes/processes.php";
```

Comment: It has to do with the path. Check where you have the main file and the include file and correct it.